# Add text label to d3 node in Force directed Graph and resize on hover

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, force-layout

I am trying to add text label to nodes in d3 Force Directed Graph, there seems to be an issue.
This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/RRUzZ/):

[image]

When I add the node name like this:

```
node.append("text")
    .attr("class", "word")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.name);
        return d.name;
    });
```

There's no change but the names are getting logged.

When i tried using [bounding box](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20110921/bounding.html) , the node labels appeared but the nodes are stacked up on the top-left corner of box while the node links are fine.This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/RRUzZ/3/) is the outcome of that effort i put in. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are adding a text element inside a circle, that won't work. You can add groups under the svg element and then append the circle and a text in each group:

```
// Create the groups under svg
var gnodes = svg.selectAll('g.gnode')
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('gnode', true);

// Add one circle in each group
var node = gnodes.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(force.drag);

// Append the labels to each group
var labels = gnodes.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
  // Update the links
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Translate the groups
  gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
  });    

});
```

A fork of your fiddle with this strategy is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/RRUzZ/20/)

Comment: Pretty much what i wanted, had to edit a bit for the re-size on hover .Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know this post is old, but note that .call(force.drag) should be on gnodes, not node.

Comment: Using `call(force.drag)` on `gnodes` would allow the user to drag the labels or the circles (everything under the groups), whereas using them in `node` only allow to drag the circles.

Comment: Where do I put the exit().remove() call? You need to have that in order to update the graph

Comment: Either before or after the `force.on('tick', callback)` call, probably inside teh `drawGraph` function on the original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/RRUzZ/