# Can't append text to d3.js force layout nodes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, force-layout

OBJECTIVE: append text to each node in a d3 force layout

BUG: text is appended to the object (I think, see console) but not displayed on screen

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidnmora/x2Lr20q7/).

[image]

```
node.append("svg:text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; }) // note that this works for
    // storing the name as the id, as seen by selecting that element by
    // it's ID in the CSS (see red-stroked node)
    .style("fill", "#555")
    .style("font-family", "Arial")
    .style("font-size", 12);
```

I'd be so grateful for any thoughts.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/18175103/173225 fix it for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add text label to d3 node in Force directed Graph and resize on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164230/add-text-label-to-d3-node-in-force-directed-graph-and-resize-on-hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add svg text to a svg circle. You should first create an svg g object (g stands for group) for each node, and than add a circle and a text for each g element, like in this code:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g");

var circle = node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
    });

var label = node.append("svg:text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill", "#555")
    .style("font-family", "Arial")
    .style("font-size", 12);
```

Of course, tick function should be updated accordingly: (also css a little bit)

```
circle.attr("cx", function (d) {
    return d.x;
})
.attr("cy", function (d) {
    return d.y;
});

label.attr("x", function (d) {
    return d.x;
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return d.y - 10;
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agam7vc4/).

[image]