# Adding labels to D3 force graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to modify [this D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) to add labels to the nodes. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sirwebber/0s1e2zm5/) replicating the code from the example.

I believe I need to edit the `start()` function since it is what is being called every time the node and edge data updates:

```
function start() {
  link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
  node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8).call(force.drag);
  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}
```

I've tried re-writing the node part of the `start()` function to append a group element (as suggested by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18175103/1590512), and then add both the text and circle nodes to the group:

```
  node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});

  // Append a group element
  node.enter().append("g");

  // Append text to the group element
  node.append("text").text(function(d) { return d.id ;});

  // Append circle to the group element
  node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; })
    .attr("r", 8);

  // Transform the group to proper location
  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')';
  });

  node.exit().remove();
```

The text node is being added correctly, but the groups are not translating to the correct locations in the figure.

I've updated the fiddle to show my current (non-working) approach.

Comment: It appears to me as if your text is getting added to the circle, but the circle is not contained in the group.  Inspect using your browser tools.  But I'm not sure exactly how to fix it.

Comment: 1. Why don't you include your attempted solution code in your attempted solution fiddle?? 2. The position of the elements of the structure are aligned with the data in the tick function. You will need to apply transforms to your g elements instead of directly positioning the circles.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CoolBlue ! I've updated the link to be what I've attempted.

Answer (score 1):

In your tick function, if you translate the node instead of the group I believe it works as you would expect:

```
function tick() {

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
  });


  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7br2t162/

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think that is almost there, but in the D3 example a node is supposed to reappear after 6 seconds. That's not happening. Any idea?

Comment: In the console, its giving an 'not found' error on this line when trying to add: link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link"). If you remove the push to the links in your function you can see the circle is correctly added back. I'll have a play around with it to see if I can figure out.

Comment: There ended up being quite a few issues, but the main thing had to do with how I was referencing the links. I was using objects as the values, instead of the index in the nodes array. I'm not too happy with my solution, but here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sirwebber/0s1e2zm5/4/) if it is helpful for anyone else.